# Ubuntu machine users logging into the same ssh session?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, shell

I'm not entirely sure of the set-up, but there is an ubuntu machine at work that we use a shared account to log in. However if anyone else is logged in on the account you enter their session. I.e. you can see what they are typing etc. I'm not too familiar with ubuntu but is this meant to happen?

Maybe it is in single-user mode? Or some special shell?

Comment: I had no idea this was even possible. It could be useful for collaboration.  I'll look forward to finding out how it's done!

Comment: Are you certain you can "see what they are typing" rather than see what they have typed?

Comment: Yes, I just tested and opened two instances of putty, when I log in I can see all the old command history of people before me and when I type I can see it in the other putty. Also when I echo $SHELL it returns /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such behavior can be achieved with forcing SSH to run GNU `screen`.

For example, if you create a user "test" on the machine, it can be granted access by inserting the below in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User test
    ForceCommand screen -x || screen
```

The `Match User test` line is optional, but prevents everybody from getting such a shared shell. The forced command acts like this:

1. If there was a previous open shell, re-attach to it (`screen -x`)
2. Otherwise, start a new shell (`screen`)

Combined with a nice [`~/.screenrc`](http://lekensteyn.nl/files/screenrc) file, you'll have a great shell experience to which you can re-attach if the connection drops.

Comment: It doesn't fit with the description.  You cannot see what is being typed in a screen session you are not connected to, and once you connect, the other person is disconnected and so cannot type into the session

Comment: That forces the user to run screen after they log in.  But does it make them share a screen session?  I guess that depends on the screen configuration?

Comment: At first I've added `multiuser on` to `~/.screenrc` but without it, it seems to work as well. If I type in one session, the other sees it too.

Comment: I don't think this is what is happening. I have checked sshd_config and there is nothing about screen in there.

Comment: @b3n In that case, check `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: keyfile is empty

Comment: It seems it was a program called [Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) managing screen in the end.

Comment: Ah well, byobu is provided with Ubuntu for managing screen profiles easier. I'm happy with mine, so I've no need for other profiles ^^